# Start service from Library Activity in Android

Tags: android, service

How could I start the service inside my project from the acitivy in the imported library in android?

Let's say : I have service A in my application project.

From activity B in imported library :

```
 protected void onPause() {

    super.onPause();

  // this.startService(A in application projet); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If feel this is simple. Create a custom `Activity` which extends `Activity` in your library and `Override` the `onCreate` and start the service.

```
public class CustomActivity extends LibraryActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    startService(new Intent(this, CustomService.class));
  }
}
```

Let me know if your see any issue.

Comment: When i create the activity in my app which extends libraryactivity, does this new activity load all resources (layout, styles ..) in the library ass well?

Comment: Sure, it will. You would need to just import the package name in this class.